# When I scroll my website it sticks when it goes over a certain section of my page. How do I fix a sticking scroll?

Tags: html, css, scroll, lag

So when I scroll down from the landing page it sticks at the next section.  I'm not sure whats happening.  There's also a white bar at the bottom of my site that i can't get rid of.  How do I fix a scrolling that seems to "stick" when it goes over a certain section and how do I fix white space at the bottom of my footer?  Here's a link a github I created to show what I'm dealing with, too much code to copy and paste here to get a good answer

https://github.com/OakHarbor/mapletest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the site, and the problem is you are using a BIG really BIG images in the background,  images like "wood1.jpg" has a resolution of 6000x4000px  this is a lot the other image "wood2.jpg" has almost 8200x5500px, just this image has 12mb this is like 4 times what a whole page should have of size, so when you're scrolling the page this images start to load so the "sticks" is the page suffering to load. 
Your imagens should be something like 800x400 or even less and don't forget to optimize them there is tools in the web that remove all the unecessary meta information check here https://imagecompressor.com

And your "white bar" is that you set a id in your tag html "noScroll" and this css was apply to it, basicly this alow you to acess the content with scroll bars, if you don't need this feature just remove it that the white bar will disappear

```
#noScroll {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: yup, this was it!  Thank you, I didnt realize how big the files were.  I made that fix and compressed the images.  There was a bunch of other stuff wrong with the site that I also found and fixed.  Could you check out the git and look at the site and let me know if everything looks fine to you?

Answer (score 0):

**For Stick Problem**

Please keep the fixed background to scroll.

**For Footer White bar**

If you want to remove the white bar from the footer, please remove `top: -50px` from #footer id and use of `margin-top: -50px` instead of this and now It will be fixed.